# can't ping VMWare 9 workstation running Win 7 on Win 8 host (or from other machines)

Tags: windows-8, vmware-workstation

The host PC is running Windows 8 with AVG. I have a new installation of VmWare Workstation 9 in which I am running a Windows 7 VM. I have configured the VM with a static IP address on the same subnet as the Windows 8 host machine. This works, I can connect to the internet and ping the host machine.

From the host machine I cannot ping the VM.

VM is configured with "Bridged" network connection.

VM has a static IP address, changing to DHCP does not help.

VM can ping IP of host PC.

AVG is set to allow all VM traffic (special option in advanced settings).

A Second physical machine can **not** ping the VM.

The VM can ping the second physical machine.

There is a single physical network card.

Disabling the firewall on the host machine does not help.

So the issue seems to be accessing the VM from outside.

The actual goal is to have the VM fully visible and configured with a static IP address so I can route internet traffic to it as a server AND be able to use its services as a server internally. Available options are: reconfigure the host or VM. Install a second NIC on host PC dedicated to the VM. Anything else you can suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling for several hours and getting no where I post here, then fix it five minutes later.

Here's what I did.

1) I had forgotten to disable/configure the default windows 7 firewall on the guest. I allowed traffic and funnily enough this granted inward access.

Some other notes for anyone attempting to do the same:

In AVG firewall (running on my host). Under settings, Advanced settings, is a tick box for "Allow any traffic from/to virtual machines supported by firewall" That needs to be ticked.

Network on the guest needs to be bridged, also "Replicate physical network connection state" needs to be ticked (Not entirely sure about that one, but other info suggested it).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.. Neither I could ping VM from host machine, nor I could connect sql server installed on host machine, from VM.  I just disabled the windows firewall on VM and everything started work fine.  My host machine is Win7 64bit with AVG and VM is WinXP.